# Zend Framework: validation of hostname

Tags: zend-framework, validation, hostname

I would like to check a hostname. 
**For exapmle:** *www.site.ru, site.ru, http://site.ru*.

These variants are correct. But: http://site.ru/ zf sets as not correct.

How to check the hostname like shown above via hostname validator?

Comment: What do you mean by "not correct"? Did you use Zend_Uri_Http::check($uri) ? Or are you trying to validate that the host exists?

Comment: Thanks for answer.
I mean "http". Because it makes error.

Comment: www.site.ru, site.ru are domains while http://www.site.ru is [URI](http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/URI) you need to manually strip the protocol/scheme part, by the way site.ru/folder/ is a correct URI but a correct hostname.
I wrote a [filter](http://borisguery.github.com/bgylibrary/#bgylib-components-bgy-filter-scheme-http) for Zend Framework, which allow you to prepend http:// to an hostname. Maybe that helps

Comment: @Boris since your filter apparently answers the question, care to put that as an answer so the @Anthony can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`www.site.ru`, `site.ru` are *domains* while http://www.site.ru is *[URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier)* you need to manually strip the protocol/scheme part, by the way `site.ru/folder/` is a correct URI but a correct hostname. I wrote a [filter](http://borisguery.github.com/bgylibrary/#bgylib-components-bgy-filter-scheme-http) for Zend Framework, which allow you to prepend http:// to an hostname. Maybe that helps